# How to parse NSData from NSURLSession to a NSArray

Tags: ios, nsarray, nsdata, nsurlsession, swift2

I'm doing a tutorial where they print the result of a `NSURLSession` as a string. But I would like to get an array out of it.

The URL I'm accessing has the following format: [24,68,69,70,71,72,73].

I think I do not fully understand how filling in a NSArray works because I cannot get this to work.

I thought simply creating a NSArray and putting in this data should do the trick, similarly as to how I can now print it:

```
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) {(data, response, error) in
     print(NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
}
```

Output:

> Optional([24,68,69,70,71,72,73])

I would also like to know why it encloses the output in "Optional()". Anyone who could clarify this for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get `[24,68,69,70,71,72,73]` from data, this data is a JSON array.

You can use Foundation's [NSJSONSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/index.html) to decode the data and cast the result to either a Foundation object like an NSArray or to a Swift array of integers.

Because it's Swift 2, `NSJSONSerialization` [throws](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH42-ID508) so you also have to use the `do try catch` syntax to handle errors.

And `Optional` is a *fundamental* type in Swift. You should read [the doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330) because it's very important to get this right. In a nutshell: an Optional is a type that contains either a value or nil. You have to "unwrap" an Optional to get the value. It's done with `if let` or `guard let` or `??` or several other ways.

Here's a simple example of all this for your array (put it inside your NSURLSession task in replacement of your `print` command):

```
do {
    if let myData = data, let myArray = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(myData, options: []) as? [Int] {
        for number in myArray {
            print(number)
        }
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

And if you *have* to use an NSArray instead of Swift array, just change the typecast:

```
do {
    if let myData = data, let myArray = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(myData, options: []) as? NSArray {
        for number in myArray {
            print(number)
        }
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```